# MySQL Stored Procedures and Last Inserted Row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm curious whether this is a possibility. I have a stored procedure which Inserts and then retrieves the last insert id. What if 2 users both use the procedure at the same time, is something like this possible?

```
 User 1
             User 2
 Insert 1
             Insert 2
 GetsLastid 2
             GetsLastid 2
```

Could the 2 calls of the stored procedure interlace the sequence of the insert queries? Or will one take lead?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a problem. From the [fine manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first `AUTO_INCREMENT` value generated for most recent statement affecting an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column *by that client*. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate `AUTO_INCREMENT` values of their own.

So the `last_insert_id()` value is always per-session (AKA *connection*) and you have two sessions in play, the can't interfere with each other's `last_insert_id()` values.

That said, it is a good idea to grab the `last_insert_id()` value and store it in a variable as soon after the INSERT as possible. If you do something else that does an INSERT behind your back — say you call another procedure that has logging added two months down the road and that logging does an INSERT — you will lose the `last_insert_id()` value that you want.